# SO Teams "Ask a private question" is pre-filled with an existing question

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to SO Teams
2. Click "Ask Private Question"

Expected: Blank form ready to fill in with new question info
Actual: Form is filled in with an existing question (as if to edit). It's always the same question, and I'm the one who asked the question.

Note that the Browser Address appears to indicate that you are creating a new question.

I have tried this in Firefox (Mac) and Edge (Windows).

Comment: Do you not have a [Discard button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peTzM.png)?

Comment: If it's helpful at all, it's likely this got cached and your browser is unaware that you posted it, which is why it still shows up - it's probably not showing up for other people in your Team.

Comment: I do have a discard button (although I didn't know I needed to use it when I was asking a new question). I just clicked it and it did indeed clear the form. So, this was user-error and not a bug? sigh.

And to respond to @Catija I tested this on two different machines, so I don't think browser cache would have been involved (on the second machine, I had never logged into Stackoverflow for Teams).

Comment: I just tested this on my Teams and the form is empty after posting it. Note that Stack Overflow has a draft feature, so if you're in the middle of writing a question/answer, the "Draft saved" text message will periodically appear under the text body, and this will be saved and restored until you post it.

Comment: Thanks for  the quick response. The question that came up all the time was one that I had submitted some time ago (at least several days ago) and was not draft. Perhaps I had edited it and left an edit in a draft state. But it was definitely not a NEW unsaved question...

EDIT: I just want to make clear that I'm cool with what I learned here. I'm the admin of the Team and I am at least armed with the knowledge in case this happens to someone else! Thanks!

Comment: @Catija it seems like that should be an answer for future reference?